# Converting Java code to php - maybe about hex to binary

Tags: java, php

I have this code here in Java that I wish to convert to PHP. It is possibly related to converting from ascii to binary, then to hex, but I am not quite sure myself. Could anybody help please?

```
String clearKey = "test";
char [] hexArray = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
byte [] bytes = clearKey.getBytes();
String keyId = "";
for (int i = 0 ; i < clearKey.length() ; i ++) {
    keyId = keyId + hexArray[(bytes[i] & 0xFF) / 16] + hexArray[(bytes[i] & 0xFF) % 16];
}
System.out.println(keyId);
```

Here is what I got so far:

The second line of the code can probably be converted into this:

```
$bytes = bin2hex($clearKey);
```

But I don't know what the equivalent of following code in php:

```
hexArray[(bytes[i] & 0xFF) / 16] + hexArray[(bytes[i] & 0xFF) % 16];
```

**Additional Information**

I converted this code into correct Java syntax.

Comment: This is not Ruby code, it looks rather like Java.

Comment: @p11y Up to the point of the missing parentheses in the for/next loop, but I'm pretty sure it is Java otherwise

Comment: @owlstead yes, there are some mistakes in the code. For example, there's also no type called `bytes`, the author probably meant `byte`. However, the array notation and the `getBytes()` immediately made me think of Java.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way for me to run this code somewhere (after some fixes in parentheses) to help me comparing the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a hex encoder using table lookup. It converts a string to bytes using the *default* character encoding of the platform. Then it converts those bytes to hexadecimals. The line you question calculates the hex digit for the high and low 4 bits of the byte. The entire line therefore encodes a single byte to two hexadecimal characters.

The PHP equivalent of this Java code is

```
$keyId = unpack('H*', $clearKey)[1];
```

Comment: Tried this, but result is different, is there anyway you could provide a proof that the code shows similarly with the java one in my question?

Comment: Nevermind my comment above, I created here: Java: http://ideone.com/MZ4TLH Php: http://ideone.com/VDYWRs